# How to force open a file in linux as a normal user

Tags: linux, docker, unix, grafana-loki, promtail

"/etc/docker/daemon.json"
"/etc/docker/daemon.json" E212: Can't open file for writing

I’m currently trying to set up a Loki server, Promtail, and Grafana as docker images

I installed all the plugins needed however when I tried editing the docker daemon config file with this command

**sudo nano /etc/docker/daemon.json**

It does not allow me to write due to permissions so I tried using

**sudo vi chmod 666 /etc/docker/daemon.json**

but this only creates a new file in my directory called chmod

The docker containers are up but I can't see the Loki metrics on my web browser when I try to use localhost:3100/metrics neither can it can be added as a Datasource

Please can you help?

Comment: Note that questions that are about using UNIX tools, not about writing software, are better asked at [unix.se].

Comment: Also, making a configuration file world-writable is an _extremely_ bad idea. It's generally better to err on the side of things being explicitly broken as opposed to "working"-but-insecure -- it's easier to fix something that simply doesn't work than to remove a rootkit someone injected into your system because you "fixed" it the fast way instead of the right way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be `sudo chmod 666 /etc/docker/daemon.json`.

What you are doing is running `vi` against 3 files, `chmod`, `666`, `/etc/docker/daemon.json`.

The directory `/etc/docker` must also exist as a directory, and not as a file.

Comment: I tried the command you suggested and got the error message 
chmod: cannot access '/etc/docker/daemon.json': No such file or directory

Comment: It doesn't exist, so it cannot change the permissions. You need to create it first. Read the last line of my answer, then run `sudo nano /etc/docker/daemon.json`

Comment: Thanks a lot. It was actually an awful mistake from my end